# Using .innerhtml to input a list with links

Tags: javascript, syntax

When I use the function below the .innerHTML works.  and the list appears under my ul element with the id of archive_content.  The only problem is when I turn the li elements to links  the function no longer works.  I was wondering if anyone knew the reasoning behind this.

```
function art()
{
//Define art content inside list below 
var archive_content =
"<li>hey</li>"+
"<li>hey</li>"+
"<li>hey</li>"+
"<li>hey</li>";

document.getElementById("archive").innerHTML='Drawings';
document.getElementById("archive_content").innerHTML= archive_content;
}
```

edit: 
This is how I tried turning them into links

```
  var archive_content =
"<li><a href="#">hey</a></li>" +
"<li><a href="#">hey</a></li>"+
"<li><a href="#">hey</a></li>"+
"<li><a href="#">hey</a></li>";
```

Comment: How about posting the code that doesn't work instead of the code that does work?

Comment: "*when I turn the li elements to links*" - How do you do this? Post the code?

Comment: As you can see, the syntax highlighter pointed out the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have double-quote characters in a sting that is bounded with double-quotes.

```
"lorem "foo" ipsum" // throws a syntax error
"lorem 'foo' ipsum" // OK
```

Use single-quotes to bound strings in JavaScript.

```
var archive_content =
'<li><a href="#">hey</a></li>' +
'<li><a href="#">hey</a></li>' +
'<li><a href="#">hey</a></li>' +
'<li><a href="#">hey</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use double quotes for both the href and the full string.  Either this:

```
var archive_content =
'<li><a href="#">hey</a></li>' +
'<li><a href="#">hey</a></li>' +
'<li><a href="#">hey</a></li>' +
'<li><a href="#">hey</a></li>';
```

or this:

```
var archive_content =
"<li><a href='#'>hey</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='#'>hey</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='#'>hey</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='#'>hey</a></li>";
```

will fix the issue.